# How to make React slick slider work with icons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-slick

There is a code that displays icons

```
switch (name) {
    case Header.Arrows.name:
        return <ArrowsComponent key={name} color={color}/>;
    case Header.Zoom.name:
        return <ZoomTool key={name} color={color}/>;
    default:
        return null;
    }
```

I want to not just display them but do it using the react slick slider. ArrowsComponent and ZoomTool are the components for icons. How to properly wrap this code in `<Slider> .. </Slider>`?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two ways

#### Method 1:

```js
switch (name) {
    case Header.Arrows.name:
        return (
          <Slider>
            <ArrowsComponent key={name} color={color}/>
          </Slider>
        );
    case Header.Zoom.name:
        return (
          <Slider>
            <ZoomTool key={name} color={color}/>
          </Slider>
        );
    default:
        return null;
    }
```

#### Method 2

```js
const renderSlider = (child) => {
  return (
    <Slider>
      {child}
    </Slider>
  );
};

switch (name) {
    case Header.Arrows.name:
        renderSlider(<ArrowsComponent key={name} color={color}/>);
    case Header.Zoom.name:
        renderSlider(<ZoomTool key={name} color={color}/>);
    default:
        return null;
    }
```

Hope that helps.